# bug in scala in for each loop while trying to loop through consumer record's

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

Cannot resolve symbol for Foreach

```
import java.util._
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer._
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer

object ConsumerExample {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val T_Name = "CarSensor"
    val T_Group_Name = "CarSensorGroup"
    val props = new Properties()

    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094")
    props.put("group.id",T_Group_Name)
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")

    val Kafka_Consumer=new KafkaConsumer[String,String](props)
    Kafka_Consumer.subscribe (Arrays.asList(T_Name))
    while(true)
    {
      val Consumer_Record=Kafka_Consumer.poll(100) //ConsumerRecords Object
      //  val RecordList=Consumer_Record.toString
      for( i <- Consumer_Record)
      { //**This place is where Cannot resolve symbol for Foreach issue shows up for <- symbol.**
        println("Supplier id = "+String.valueOf(i.value().getID())+ "Supplier name = " +i.value().getID())
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have used <- symbol in many examples before it worked.
I thought it was an issue with Intelliji and restarted it. Its a problem in object getting casted to different type I guess.

Answer (score 2):

```
  Consumer_Record.forEach(i => {
    println("Supplier id = "+String.valueOf(i.value().getID())+ "Supplier name = " +i.value().getID())
  })
```

works fine for me.

Except `String` doesn't have `getID()` method.

You can use `for(i <- Consumer_Record.asScala)` if you want `for` syntax, but you have to add `import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._`.

Answer (score 0):

```
val Kafka_Consumer=new KafkaConsumer[String,String](props)

Kafka_Consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(T_Name))

while(true) {

  val Consumer_Record=Kafka_Consumer.poll(100) //ConsumerRecords Object

  for( i <- Consumer_Record.asScala) {
    println("Supplier id = "+String.valueOf(i.value())+ " Supplier name = " +i.key())
  }
}
```